# Gracefull shutdown, close db connections, opened files, stop work on SIGTERM, in multiprocessing

Tags: python, database, multiprocessing, signals

I have a daemon process witch spawns child processes using `multiprocessing` to do some work, each child process opens its own connection handle do DB (postgres in my case). Jobs to processes are passed via `Queue` and if queue is empty processes invoke `sleep` for some time, and recheck queue

How can I implement "graceful shutdown" on SIGTERM? Each subprocess should terminate as fast as possible, with respect of closing/terminating current cursor/transaction and db connection, and opened files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store all the open files/connections/etc. in a global structure, and close them all and exit in your SIGTERM handler.